# Windowbuilder Pro - selectedElement binding not working

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, swing, windowbuilder

Following a tutorial trying to learn Windowbuilder Pro and running into some problems.

I have a list of an object, and want to create a binding function so that that when I've selected an object in the list, the corresponding objects name will appear in a button.

This type of operation never works for me. No object-specific options appear in the "selectedElement" column, just .

If I try to bind say a button to a specific beans property, it works well.

The documentation for Windowbuilder is so sparse I didn't think of anywhere else to turn.

Greatly appreciate any help with solving the problem or resources for learning Windowbuilder indepth. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should point out the WindowBuilder docs on Swing Data Binding are expressly intended to document how to use the WB tools and not how to use the Swing Data Binding API itself. In fact, WindowBuilder expects you to have a fairly good grasp of Swing Data Binding fundamentals before you can effectively use the tools it provides.

Based on your question, it sounds like you need to create an  as described in the WB docs [here](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/features/swing/data_binding/swing_bindings.html). To understand what an  is and how to use it, you should refer to the Swing Data Binding docs themselves.

The bottom line is that, if you know how to create the Swing Data Bindings that you need by hand (in source), you should be able to more rapidly create then using WindowBuilder. WB strives to expose the Swing DB API in as pure a form as possible (warts and all). We have intentionally tried to expose the full power of the DB API without adding any simplification layer on top of it. The downside is that, if you are new to the Swing DB API and don't know how it all is intended to work, WB will not help you or teach you how to use it.